# Checking if a variable is either true or false

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I have a variable initialized with `undefined`. Now I'd like to check if it is either `true` or `false`.

Is there a statement more elegant than the following?

```
if (isValid === true || isValid === false) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about checking if it is not undefined?

- If it is neither true, nor false it has to be undefined.
- So if it is not undefined, it is set and therefore either true or false.

```
if (isValid !== undefined) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Technically, the variable can now contain a number or a string now. However, if that's not expected, it should be fine to just check for NOT `undefined` instead of `true` or `false`, if those are the only three expected options.